# fsck from a Windows box

Tags: windows, fsck

Is there any program that is totally equivalent to `fsck` for ext2/3/4 partitions and runs in **Windows**?

I need it to scan & repair my Android phone's `sd-ext` partition on SD. I also know that Windows only mounts the firts partition on a removable drive. I need the utility to scan the second partition on the SD card, like `/dev/mmcblk0p2` on my Linux laptop

Comment: The "correct answer" mark should probably be moved to the other answer, that answers the specific question of "fcsk on Windows", without using a LiveCD.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't hear about `fsck` for windows, but you may download any LiveCD image of linux, make the bootable CD or usb flash disk (you may download the Windows version of `Live USB creator` [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/))

Comment: +1 because I did this in the meantime. Running the live distro on Virtualbox didn't work because VB has some troubles sharing some USB devices, including USB to micro SD adapters

Comment: This `VirtualBox` issue is not related to your question :)

Answer (score 11):

Ext2Fsd is an ext* file system driver for Windows , gpl2 license and FREE, support a lot of features that you can find in fsck , here is the link to check http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Comment: Whoa! I didn't remember that ext2fsd includes an fsck wrapper too. I'll try it ASAP. Thanks

Comment: it only seems support so called "fast fsck" which should better be named "journal replay" for transactional ext3/4, seems support nothing for ext2 :-(

Comment: This should be marked as the "correct answer" since it is actually what the poster asked for.

Comment: I was looking for the same question & right after reading your answer I opened Ext2fsd but I couldn't found 'fsck' feature. Could you please help? I tried up looking to official website that doesn't exist too.

Comment: [Do not use this tool!](https://github.com/matt-wu/Ext3Fsd/issues/26)

Answer (score 1):

paragon's linux tools will verify and fix ext* partitions, same as fsck. it has resurrected my dual boot fedora many times. you just need to make sure its not mounted first its pretty simple, albeit shareware. though the reliable r/w mounting ability is worth the cost.

https://www.paragon-software.com/us/home/linuxfs-windows/

i am not affiliated them